# how to insert Time only to my SQl database

Tags: php, mysql

i have form for user to input his information and the time he will be available , so no one can send him message only in the time he is there

i use coulm in the database to store the time using type TIME

in the register page i ask him to insert the time in input

```
<input name="time" type="time" class="email" placeholder="Time" required />
```

then insert form is

```
 if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbladmin (strName, strPassword, intNumber, strAddress, strEmail, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['strName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['strPassword'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['intNumber'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['strAddress'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['time'], "time"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['strEmail'], "text"));
```

i get error when trying to insert the time here

```
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['time'], "time"),
```

after this problem fix

what will be the if statement that will say if the time is after that or before another time do something  , what i mean here is he but start time 10 am and end time 10 pm , so no one can send him message only in this time

Comment: upppppppppppppppppppppppppppp